# Unit test using SecretClient in Azure Key Vault Secrets client

Tags: azure, unit-testing, mockito, python-unittest, azure-keyvault

I use a try/except block for catching ServiceRequestError in case the key vault name does not exist. Whatever I do, I get DID NOT RAISE <class 'azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError'>.

`app.py`

```
from azure.identity import DeviceCodeCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ServiceRequestError

def key_vault(keyvault_name):
    credential = DeviceCodeCredential()
    kv_uri = f"https://{keyvault_name}.vault.azure.net"
    client = SecretClient(vault_url=kv_uri, credential=credential)

    try:
        set_secret = client.set_secret("name", "client_id")
    except ServiceRequestError as non_exist_keyvault_error:
        print(non_exist_keyvault_error.message)
        sys.exit(1)
```

It doesn't work though, and I can't get my head around what's wrong.

My guess is that I need to mock the mocking a KeyVaultClient (`azure.keyvault.secrets._client.SecretClient object`) which is difficult

`test.py`

```
import app
from mockito import when, mock, unstub
import pytest
from azure.core.exceptions import ServiceRequestError 



when(app).DeviceCodeCredential().thenReturn(credential)
keyvault_name = "keyvault_foo"
kv_uri = f"https://{keyvault_name}.vault.azure.net"
client = mock()
when(app).SecretClient(vault_url=kv_uri, credential=credential).thenReturn(client)

with pytest.raises(ServiceRequestError) as err:
     app.key_vault(keyvault_name)

msg = "Failed to establish a new connection" 
assert msg in str(err.value)
assert err.type == ServiceRequestError
```